# Dynamically password protect a page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, password-protection

Is it possible to dynamically password protect a page in Wordpress?

For example if the following page is visited:

http://example.com - Allow visitors to see the page

But if the following URL is visited:

http://example.com/?token=123 - Dynamically set a password on fly from the code

Comment: are you talking about set password to particular page from admin in word press?

Comment: No, I'm talking about a way to do this from the code, something like setPassword('password', $page_id) for example